# Python - input error from user

Tags: python, input

```
   from subprocess import Popen

   counter =0

   while True:
      i= raw_input('enter an integer')
      i = int(i)

      if counter == 0:
            if i == 1:
                    play = Popen (['omxplayer audio_tart.mp3'], shell = True)
                    m=i
                    counter+=1
            elif i == 2:
                    play = Popen(['omxplayer audio_lemon.mp3'], shell = True)
                    m=i
                    counter+=1
      elif counter!=0:
            if i == m:
                    print "same input"
                    pass
            elif i == 1:
                    play = Popen(['omxplayer audio_tart.mp3'], shell = True)
                    m=i
                    counter+=1
            elif i == 2:
                    play = Popen(['omxplayer audio_lemon.mp3'], shell = True)
                    m=i
                    counter+=1
```

Hi guys, I'm pretty new to python and this is my simplified version of code. I'm basically trying to get multiple inputs while comparing them from a user. Eg. if the input(variable i) is the same as the previous i, do something... When i first enter a valid integer, it works fine but i got an error after entering the second valid input.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "2.py", line 7, in <module>
    i = int(i)
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Also, I've tried the following code for user input:

```
    i= input('enter an integer')
```

and got this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "2.py", line 6, in <module>
    i= int(input('enter an integer'))
    File "<string>", line 0

      ^
    SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Would appreciate if someone could help
PS: I'm using python 2.7

Comment: When it says `enter an integer` directly key in the numbers. Do not press the <enter> key. Else change the statement to `i= raw_input('enter an integer\n')`

Comment: hi, the program isnt really responding without the 'enter' key

Comment: Directly enter the number, please don't press enter until you type the number.

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    while True:
        try:
            i = int(raw_input(...))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Please enter a number')
    if counter == 0:
    ...
```

This will loop until the user enters a value that can be properly cast as an integer. Be aware that this will allow a user to enter any number. If there are other constraints you need to account for those.

Comment: hi thanks for commenting, im actually trying to compare the first user input with the second input if they are they same, if they are the same, i'll perform some operations.. but not checking if the user is inputting an integer or not

Comment: The description of what you are trying to do in this comment doesn't match your code. What second input? The `ValueError` is coming from passing an empty string into `input()`, so that's why my answer fixes that. Please fix your question.

Comment: Basically, the program will keep on looping for user input and play the appropriate .mp3 according to the user selection. If the current input is not equal to the previous input, i'll do something(killing the current process and play the new input audio). The code above was just a simply one from my idea.

Comment: sorry if it's a bit misleading. Also, I've tried your method and got EOFError at this line "i = int(raw_input('enter an integer\n'))" when attempting to enter another input

Comment: What other input? Please edit your question to match the code you actually have and the errors you are getting not an idea that you have.